# RTrouble passing arguments to action

Tags: hooks, actions, variables, parameter

I know there are several posts on this topic. I have followed many of them as well as other resources on the web and thought I had it down, but it does not seem to be working. In my case, I have 2 functions hooked to 2 separate actions that need the same data.

```
$data = array('red', 'green', 'blue');

do_action('use_colors_here', $data);
add_action('wp_body_open', 'use_colors_here', 10, 1); 
function use_colors_here($data) {
  $out = '<h1>Colors</h1>';
  $out .= '<p>Color 1: ' . $data[1] . '</p>';
  $out .= '<p>Color 2: ' . $data[2] . '</p>';

  echo $out;
}

do_action('use_colors_there', $data);
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'use_colors_there', 10, 1); 
function use_colors_there($data) {
  wp_enqueue_script('color-script-1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/colors_' . $data[1] . '.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('color-script-2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/colors_' . $data[2] . '.js');
}
```

The expected behavior was for the values of `$data[1]` and `$data[2]` (green and blue respectively) to be accessible by the 2 functions and printed out in the markup each is responsible for adding to the page. Unfortunately, `$data` was not accessible inside the functions and I end up with markup looking like:

```
<h1>Colors</h1>
<p>Color 1: </p>
<p>Color 2: </p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE

After reading a bit closer, I see that I have to use the hook rather than the function name as the 1st argument of `do_action`. So I changed it to:

```
do_action('wp_body_open', $data);
```

and it seems to be working.

### FINAL CODE (using accepted answer)

```
function get_component_config() {
  return ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
}

add_action('wp_body_open', 'use_colors_here'); 
function use_colors_here() {
  $data = get_component_config();
  $out = '<h1>Colors</h1>';
  $out .= '<p>Color 1: ' . $data[1] . '</p>';
  $out .= '<p>Color 2: ' . $data[2] . '</p>';

  echo $out;
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'use_colors_there'); 
function use_colors_there() {
    $data = get_component_config();
    wp_enqueue_script('color-script-1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/colors_' . $data[1] . '.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('color-script-2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/colors_' . $data[2] . '.js');
}
```

Comment: i'm a little confused, none of your action names seem to match, you tried to fire an action named `use_colors_here` but no functions were added to that action so it does nothing. Then you have a function with that same name added to an unrelated action `wp_body_open`, but you try to use a `$data` argument, but `wp_body_open` does not provide any arguments! And then, you fire off a 3rd action `use_colors_there` that has nothing added to it either, so that doesn't do anything ( was this a typo? _there? _here? ).

Comment: I suspect you've fallen into the X Y problem trap. Would I be right that your actual problem is displaying the colours on the body open action? And that all of the action stuff you asked about it just you trying to figure out how to solve that problem? I also see you have a `use_colors_there` function, but it's not used anywhere

Comment: @TomJNowell - yes that sounds about right. I believe I've misused `add_action`. I'm trying to pass `$data` to both functions, `use_colors_here` and `use_colors_there`, which hook to `wp_body_open` and `wp_enqueue_scripts` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an action hook named `use_colors_here` and you run the hook using `do_action( 'use_colors_here', $data )`, but I don't see where you call `add_action()` for that hook?

I mean, the [`do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) and [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) should be used like so:

```php
// This adds a callback to the use_colors_here hook.
add_action( 'use_colors_here', 'some_function' );

// And this is the callback which accepts one parameter from the use_colors_here hook.
function some_function( $data ) {
    var_dump( $data );
}

// And this do_action() executes the above callback (and other callbacks added to the
// `use_colors_here` hook).
$data = array( 'red', 'green', 'blue' );
do_action( 'use_colors_here', $data );
```

### UPDATE <sup>(revised)</sup>

> I see that I have to use the hook rather than the function name as the
> 1st argument of `do_action`

Yes that's right, the first parameter for `do_action()` is indeed the hook name, whereas the second and the rest of parameters are the parameters passed to the hook callbacks — but in the case of two or more parameters, you need to use the 4th parameter for `add_action()` to specify the number of parameters that your callback accepts.

```php
// This fires the some_hook hook which has two parameters.
do_action( 'some_hook', 'param 1', 'param 2' );

// So when adding your action, if you want (to access) both the above parameters
// from your callback, then you must set the 4th parameter below to 2.
add_action( 'some_hook', 'some_function', 10, 2 );

function some_function( $param1, $param2 ) {
    var_dump( $param1, $param2 );
}
```

And `do_action()` (although indirectly) actually uses [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to run the actions for a specific (action) hook, or to run the callbacks registered to run on that hook, so if you understand how `call_user_func_array()` works, then you'd also understand how `do_action()` works.

```php
function my_callback( $foo, $bar ) {
    var_dump( $foo, $bar, __FUNCTION__ );
}

$data = 'using call_user_func_array()';
// this calls my_callback() directly
call_user_func_array( 'my_callback', array( $data, 'second param' ) );

add_action( 'hook_name', 'my_callback', 10, 2 );
$data = 'using do_action()';
// but this fires the "event"/hook named hook_name and then it calls
// my_callback() indirectly via call_user_func_array()
// i.e. it calls call_user_func_array( 'my_callback', array( $data, 'yay, it works!' ) )
do_action( 'hook_name', $data, 'yay, it works!' );
```

> I just need to be able to access `$data` from inside my 2 functions,
> `use_colors_here` and `use_color_there`

Then you're doing it correctly, i.e. when you do `do_action('wp_body_open', $data)`, the `$data` will be passed to your 2 functions (and all other actions/callbacks for the hook).

But without calling `do_action()` manually *and without using the `global` keyword or even `$GLOBALS`*, the other possible way to access the `$data` variable is by using a closure; however, the drawback is that it'll be next to impossible to remove the specific action using `remove_action()` — because closures are anonymous functions, so what name would we use when removing the action?

```php
add_action( 'some_hook', 'some_function', 10, 2 );
// that can be easily removed like so:
remove_action( 'some_hook', 'some_function', 10 );

$data = array( 'red', 'green', 'blue' );
add_action( 'some_hook', function () use ( $data ) {
    var_dump( $data );
} );
// now with that one, how do we remove it?
//remove_action( 'some_hook', ??, 10 );
```

Therefore, if you just wanted to get access to the data in the `$data`, then you could use a custom function which returns the data:

```php
function get_colors() {
    return array( 'red', 'green', 'blue' );
}

add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'use_colors_here' );
function use_colors_here() {
    $data = get_colors();
    var_dump( $data );
}
```

> I thought it would be better to keep everything in `functions.php`
> rather than adding more code to `header.php`... just for
> organizational purposes.

Yes (although not exactly "everything"), I thought the same as well. But in my original "Update" section, I was just saying you could (or that it's just fine if you) explicitly call your actions after the hook is fired. I.e.

```php
// Let's say you define $data here. (in same file or block of code)
$data = array( 'red', 'green', 'blue' );

// So instead of..
do_action( 'wp_body_open', $data );

// You can do..
wp_body_open(); // this fires the wp_body_open hook
use_colors_here( $data );

// But that means, use_colors_here() should no longer be hooked on to the hook.
```

> Does calling the function directly in `header.php` have any significant performance advantages?

No, but calling it directly means you can easily pass the `$data` and other parameters..

Otherwise, for local variables like the `$data` above, then we would need to use a closure in order to access the *variable* (and eventually the data inside or referenced to by that variable).

Comment: I'm a little confused. I thought I was following the example correctly, but I guess not. In the end, I just need to be able to access `$data` from inside my 2 functions, `use_colors_here` and `use_color_there`.

Comment: In that case, then you can't do it the way you've done it. Because the `$data` variable is indeed not accessible from inside the functions. However, you could try using closure - or yes, that `do_action('wp_body_open', $data);` also works - but I wonder why are you calling the hook manually..

Comment: what do you mean by "calling the hook manually"?

Comment: I mean, if you're developing a theme, you could just do `<?php wp_body_open(); ?>` in `header.php` and the hook will be called automatically.

Comment: That is in my `header.php`. So does that mean I don't have to use `do_action('wp_body_open', $data)`? If not, where/how do I pass $data to the function on that hook (`use_colors_here()`)?

Comment: Does the "Update" help?

Comment: Yes, I think so... still digesting a bit. I thought it would be better to keep everything in `functions.php` rather than adding more code to `header.php`... just for organizational purposes. Does calling the function directly in `header.php` have any significant performance advantages? Thanks for sticking with me here, btw.

Comment: @Daveh0 it's best to think of hooks and actions as events on a timeline. `add_action` is the same as  _"when this event happens, run this"_, and `do_action` is the same as _"omg the event is happening, run all the things we were asked to run"_. It makes more sense that way, especially since the order of things matters  ( if you ask it to run something on `init` after `init` has happened, it won't run, as that requires time travel, it's already happened! It's like trying to board a train after it's left )

Comment: @Daveh0 does the "Update 2" help?

Comment: Yeah i get the part about `add_action` being like an event listener/handler. Still a little confused about how the `do_action` part works, but I think I just need to read a bit more. Since `wp_body_open` is present in more than 1 template (or at least it's possible for it to be), and I want the ability to insert this component (in my watered down example, something displaying the names of a few colors) into every page on the site, it seems to make more sense doing it globally from `functions.php`  rather than having to hard-code the function call into every template.

Comment: @Daveh0 Thanks for accepting my answer, but because your updated question says, "using accepted answer", then I added the `get_colors()` part back to my answer. Cheers!